# Repairing failed apt upgrade

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, overheating

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, and I made an `apt upgrade`recently.

The command took many minutes, and, when it was with a completion of 99%, setting up man-db, the server overheated and switched off suddenly.

When I restarted the server, I was able to access the server, as normally, using `ssh`.

However, some problems may have arisen from the interruption of the `apt upgrade` script.

What can I do to repair my server?

OS: Ubuntu Server 18.04.6 LTS
Machine: old laptop i386 (Pentium M)

Comment: `sudo dpkg  --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: If it powered off uncleanly; I'd suggest booting a *live* system on it first, and perform file-system checks.  If no errors are found/corrected; then I'd boot in normally & try and continue to aborted command or as @nobody suggested.  Yes older hardware (pentium M) can turn off when too hot, which is usually a warning sign of dead/dying fan that needs replacing - so check your hardware as you're describing a failing device in need to attention.

Comment: FYI:  They turn off when they reach 100oC usually... ie. your hardware needs attention, fans replaced quite possible, clean etc & may have other components in need of attention.

Comment: `sudo dpkg  --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install` solved the question. Thanks

Comment: Great do not forget to check your Hardware like guiverc wrote